# Python, PIL; Text to Image and fonts

Tags: python, image, text, python-imaging-library, bold

I have an issue with writing text to an image under Python and PIL -
I'm able to write text to a png file, though not bold text. Could anyone provide an example of how to achieve this?

I thought the easiest solution *may be* was use a bold-variant of a text, but I'm unable to see anything in the Windows/font folder that supplies this - does this mean font types have a 'bold attribute' that is T/F?:
[image: quick look for bold-fonts under windows]

Code I'm using:

```
import PIL
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

# font = ImageFont.truetype("Arial-Bold.ttf",14)
font = ImageFont.truetype("Arial.ttf",14)
img=Image.new("RGBA", (500,250),(255,255,255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((0, 0),"This is a test",(0,0,0),font=font)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
img.save("a_test.png")
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You aren't looking at actual font files in the control panel (explorer magically turns into the font viewer control panel when in the Windows/fonts folder as well), they are grouped by family for your convenience. Double click the family to see the fonts in the family:

[image]

Then right-click and choose properties to find the file name:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Pavel, that worked fine: font = ImageFont.truetype("**Arialbd.ttf**",14)

Answer (score 17):

A simple way to do it:

```
font = ImageFont.load_default().font
```

Also you can do a [google search for 'verdana.ttf'](http://www.fontpalace.com/font-download/Verdana/) and download it put it in the same directory as the python file:

Then add it like this:

```
font = ImageFont.truetype("Verdana.ttf",14)
```